# Building ROS android_sensors_driver Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, ros

I'm having issues building a project with gradle on Ubuntu 14.04. The project in particular is the ROS android_sensors_driver project. I get a [build error](http://txs.io/htyb) after executing gradlew clean debug. The offending line is    compile project(':android-15')    . I think that it is looking for the android-15 platform in the SDK. I have set ANDROID_HOME to the directory where the SDK is located.  The project was cloned from [here](https://github.com/chadrockey/android_sensors_driver). The build.gradle file is.

```
dependencies {
  compile "org.ros.rosjava_core:rosjava:0.2.0"
  compile "org.ros.rosjava_core:rosjava_tutorial_pubsub:[0,)"
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
  compile project(':android-15')

}


apply plugin: 'android'

/*debug.dependsOn project(':android_gingerbread_mr1').tasks.debug*/

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        applicationId "org.ros.android.android_sensor_driver"
        targetSdkVersion 15
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
```

Any ideas what the issue might be. Let me know what extra info you might need. I'm reasonably new to linux and gradle?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the compiler are saying that the class android has no function android() that receive the parameters are you passing:

**MissingMethodException: Could not find method android() for arguments**

Check if the arguments that you are sending to the method are the same needed and if the class has some function overloading to a method that receive these arguments you are giving.

I hope it help!

Comment: The challenge is probably that the poster didn't write this code, they cloned it from a repository that presumably worked for someone else, with some version of the SDK and some setup.  So the real question is, why isn't it working in the poster's setup?

Comment: Maybe he are using the function in a wrong way. With parameters with wrong type being send to the function. The exception that had make the compile stop was the MIssingMethodException, I think that the compiler found the function, but it doesn't receive the arguments that the poster is passing.

Comment: Again, you are missing that this presumably *worked for someone before*.

Comment: I ran an issue as well in a fresh android-studio snap install on ubuntu 18.04 with the same git project:    
`Could not find method compile() for arguments [org.ros.rosjava_core:rosjava:0.2.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
Open File`